# Simple way to search (filter) multiple items within ng-repeat table? AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, search, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to find a simple way to make a search more in-depth by allowing multiple things to be searched. i.e. If I was searching for cars, instead of just typing "Honda", I could type "Honda, black, 2001".

Here is a skeleton of my current layout.

`<input type="text" ng-model="search.$" placeholder="Search by: Name, Summoner, Elo, Role, Champion, ect..">`

```
<table>
   <tbody ng-repeat="actors in Users | orderBy:orderByField:reverseSort | filter:search">
   <tr class="col-xs-12" ng-click="showDetails = ! showDetails">
          <td class="col-xs-2">{{actors.name}}</td>
          <td class="col-xs-2">{{actors.summoner}}</td>
          <td class="col-xs-2">{{actors.school}}</td>
          <td class="col-xs-2">{{actors.rank}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-show="showDetails">
          {{actors.other_stuff}}
    </tr>            
   </tbody>
</table>
```

So right now, when I type into my search box it will give me information that literally appears anywhere within my table, which is fine. However, that usually returns very broad results. I am trying to find a way to allow users to search for more specific items via filtering by multiple words.

Going back to the car example if I searched for "Honda black 2001" this would give me nothing as it looks for the entire string "Honda black 2001", not "Honda" AND "black" AND "2001", I am trying to find a simple way to search via multiple words with Angular, like using a comma for separation. Is this simple to do in Angular?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure how simple it is, but you could use a filter and controller function that implements this type of filtering.

Using your car example, the markup might be something like:

```
  <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="q" placeholder="Search by year, make, model" />
  <br/>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="car in cars | filter:filterCars">{{car.year}} {{car.make}} {{car.model}}</li>
  </ul>
```

The controller stuff

```
  $scope.cars = [
  {
    year: 2006,
    make: 'BMW',
    model: 'M3'
  },
  {
    year: 2006, 
    make: 'BMW',
    model: 'Z4'
  },
  {
    year: 1992, 
    make: 'Mazda',
    model: 'Miata'
  },
  {
    year: 2008, 
    make: 'BMW',
    model: '750'
  }
  ];

  var match = function (item, val) {
    var regex = new RegExp(val, 'i');
    return item.year.toString().search(regex) == 0 ||
           item.make.search(regex) == 0 ||
           item.model.search(regex) == 0;
  };

 $scope.filterCars = function(car) {
    // No filter, so return everything
    if (!$scope.q) return true;
    var matched = true;

    // Otherwise apply your matching logic
    $scope.q.split(' ').forEach(function(token) {
        matched = matched && match(car, token); 
    });

    return matched;
  };
```

There are some edge cases that probably aren't covered here, but you get the idea.

Working [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/Aowec7MzflOdPjPRgVHE)